# How to parse this xml file which have two root elements?

Tags: python, xml

```
<objects>
   <object>
      <record>
            <net_amount>3657.82</net_amount>
            <order_number>47004603</order_number>
            <invoice_source>Email</invoice_source>
            <invoice_capture_date>2022-11-13</invoice_capture_date>
            <document_type>INVOICE</document_type>
            <data_capture_provider_code>00001</data_capture_provider_code>
            <data_capture_provider_reference>594826</data_capture_provider_reference>
            <document_capture_provide_code>00002</document_capture_provide_code>
            <document_capture_provider_ref>594826</document_capture_provider_ref>
      </record>
   </object>
</objects>
```

how can i parse this xml data. this data have two "object" elements. when i remove one "object" i am able to parse this. but otherwise i cannot parse it.

```
for file in files:
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot()
    for i in root.findall("record"):
        net_amount = i.find("net_amount").text
        order_number = i.find("order_number").text
```

when i use this above code i want to get the "net_amount" and "order_number". but when i remove one object from the xml file it works fine. but i have so many files like this. is there any method to make it work. please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've done the hard part already, all you have to do is to wrap your code in a loop that will go through the `object` tags.

```py
for file in files:
    tree = ET.parse(file)
    root = tree.getroot() #This is the outer "objects" tags
    for obj in root.findall("object"): #Loop over all object in it
        for i in obj.findall("record"): #Resume the original search in the specific object tag rather than the outer one
            net_amount = i.find("net_amount").text
            order_number = i.find("order_number").text
```

Comment: Thank you so much . it worked. i was in a critical situation.